# Flutter - PopupMenuItem - how get value

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, popupmenu

I have a list that appears when you click on the button in `BottomNavigationBarItem`. This is the `showMenu` list with the code that is below.

But how can I get the value selected in this list?

```dart
showMenu<int>(
  context: context,
  position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(1000.0, 600.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  items: <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
    new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 1'), value: 1),
    new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 2'), value: 2),
    new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 3'), value: 3),
    new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 4'), value: 4),
  ],
  elevation: 8.0,
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the user chooses a `PopupMenuItem`, that value will be returned by the `showMenu` function.

So you can get the value by assigning to a variable:

```
var selected = await showMenu(
        context: context,
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(1000.0, 600.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        items: <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 1'), value: 1),
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 2'), value: 2),
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 3'), value: 3),
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(child: const Text('Top 4'), value: 4),
        ]);
```

You can see below that when we print `selected`, we get the `value` of that `PopupMenuItem`

[image]

**EDIT**: 
If you check the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showMenu.html) for the `showMenu` function on Flutter's webpage, you'll see that it returns a `Future`, that's why I used `await` in front of `showMenu` function.